# Iterating/Parsing this JSON response

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a few JSON feeds in my app, which parse correctly, using valid grammar and use of keys. I use a methodology similar to the following:

```
try {

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    if(jsonObj.length() > 0){
        Iterator keys = jsonObj.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get(key);

            String myString = obj.get("fieldname").toString();

            ...
        }
    }
} catch(e) {
    ...
}
```

However, one JSON feed I have is styled like the following which needs to be parsed slightly differently:

```
{
"10":["111","aaa","bbb","213sdg","1.0","-0.343"],
"20":["111","aaa","bbb","213sdg","1.0","-0.343"],
"30":["111","aaa","bbb","213sdg","1.0","-0.343"],
"40":["111","aaa","bbb","213sdg","1.0","-0.343"],
"50":["111","aaa","bbb","213sdg","1.0","-0.343"]
}
```

I've tried using `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` but still the try{} clause is catching an error for requiring a fieldname/key when the feed has no fieldnames/keys.

Is there a simple way to iterate this style feed, without having to get the feed output changed? Many thanks

**EDIT**: Changed JSON object keys to show that I'm actually using different numbers

Comment: You only have one JsonObject in your json. Why are using second jsonObject in your while loop?

Comment: That code doesn't apply to the JSON I posted. The second obj was to get a JSONObject of the "row" to then parse and get the field value of that row.

Comment: your row doesn't have any jsonobject. your array simply contain strings

Comment: Ok, so back to my Post, how would I modify the code to now parse that new feed? Is each Row just an array of strings now?

Comment: Main problem is you have all json array with same key so anyhow untill you change that your code will throw exception. And yes each row is simply array of string.

Comment: That was just an example of the format. Each key is actually different :)

Comment: just use for loop for json array and fetch your strings from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, was simpler than I thought. Just refer to each "row" as a JSONArray and parse using column indexes:

```
try {

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    if(jsonObj.length() > 0){
        Iterator keys = jsonObj.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            JSONArray rowArr = jsonObj.getJSONArray(key);

            String fieldone = rowArr.getString(0);
            String fieldtwo = rowArr.getString(1);           

            ...
        }
    }
} catch(e) {
    ...
}
```

Thanks for your inputs, chaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
try{
  JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(yourStringFromYourQuestion);

  // To get one specific element:
  JSONObject w1 = jObject.getJSONObject("10");
  JSONObject w2 = jObject.getJSONObject("20");

  // Iterate over all elements
  Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
  while( keys.hasNext() ) {
  String key = (String)keys.next(); // "10", etc
  if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {

   try {
  // jsonString is a string variable that holds the JSON 
   JSONArray itemArray=jObject.getJSONArray(key);
   for (int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++) {
     int value=itemArray.getInt(i);
     Log.e("json", i+"="+value);
    }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
 } catch (JSONException e){
  Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failure converting JSON String", e);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, your `String score = entry.optString("score", "");` relies on the JSON having the fields mapped with keys, eg `"score":"123","alive":"yes",etc`. I don't have that mapping with keys

Comment: Thanks. Yep that makes sense. As this is quite a large JSON download, in order to minimise the download time, fieldnames have been omitted. So keys are gone. Is my original code not parseable with the JSONArray object then?

Comment: I mentioned that I don't want to change the feed, and that I want to parse the feed without keys, if possible